# Waiting until the whole page load

Tags: javascript, selenium, rselenium

Using the following we can expect/know that the whole page has loaded.

```
Sys.sleep(5)
```

or

```
remDr$executeScript("return document.readyState == 'complete';")
```

or

```
remDr$setTimeout(type = "page load", milliseconds = 10000)
```

However sometimes the load of page it takes longer the a general exception stops the problem. A way is to set a timer so after checking if the page loaded or not increase the time to wait or not.

Is there any simpler solution?

Comment: @baao thank you but is it possible to it in selenium?

Comment: Can you use this? : `remDr$executeScript("$(window).on('load',function{//Your code here...})")`

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$(window).on("load", function{
    //Your code here...
});
```